# Done update and insert each two together, How is it?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to update data in a database, in page update that is, adding new input that users can add new input and put value in it.

For example, I have `2` input with values in page update (values these two input get[`select`] from database table and preparing for update[`edit`] by user) user adding `1` new input and put value in it. Now the problem is here that I want update it tow input that was edit by user and I insert new input that user put value in it, both together.

How is it?

**Example from inputs:** http://jsfiddle.net/aVF7M/4/

My code (is example):

```
$id       = array('1','2','3');
$how       = $this->input->post('how');
$data = array();
foreach ($how as $idx => $name) {
    $data = array(
        '$how' => $$how[$idx],
    );
$this->db->update('hotel_units', $data, array('id' => $id[$idx]));
//$this->db->insert_batch('hotel_units', $data2);
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you rephrase this? This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Do you understand my purpose? Understand what?

Comment: Your phrasing of the question is kinda cryptic, maybe try re-writing with a little more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have a function that is fired when focus is lost. e.g. when the user edits a field (either an existing one or a new one) and clicks outside the input, the data gets serialized and sent to the URL where you handle the db interaction.

```
$('.number').blur(function(){
    alert($('form').serialize());
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:'/url/to/addDataToDB',
          data: $('form').serialize(),
          success: function(response){
                alert(resonse.responseText);
          },
          dataType: dataType
    });
})
```

Or you could have a submit button.